# SQL Injection attack testing dataset

Tags: security, sql-injection, intrusion-detection

There are some web based IDSs which improve the security of web application against SQLIA attacks. One of them is PHP-IDS. I did some changes in the working algorithem of this IDS and now I want to test the performance of both my model & PHP-IDS and show the differences on chart.Therefore, I need an attack dataset which I can give as input into these apps.
I don't want to use applications, like those exists inside backtrack. I need some text which are clean or might be infected with SQLIA. Then I can use the same dataset for both IDSs to compare their performance output.

Please note that I am trying to improve the CPU usage & RAM usage...
Do you know any existing dataset for testing and bench marking IDSs for SQL Injection attack?

Answer (score 1):

To tell you truth, it is not whatever IDS that protect you from attacks but [properly formatted queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).
So, instead of burdening your RAM and CPU making them run pointless software, better focus on programming and using proper SQL formatting.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. My major is info-sec. For doing my thesis I am trying to improve the performance of web based IDSs.

Comment: 1. For testing performance, you don't need no real dataset. Just dummy data is enough. 2. Being info-sec you are supposed to write such lists yourself. 3. Being infosec, you should know that no black-list approach can be considered reliable.

Comment: 1&2.hmm the last choice is that i enter my own data... First I was looking for some premade standard datasets. 3. I did research on anomaly and signature based, each one got its own pros and cons. I studied my master by course therefore the focus is not on final project and the contribution should be small. Then I took this one to improve the performance of existing IDSs. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AmirSa There is no such thing as a standard SQL injection dataset. I mean, what norm should it follow? But there are several automated SQL injection exploitation tools that you could use. However, there are no malicious input patterns per se; it depends on how you process the input data. And most DB engines allow several syntactical ‘distractions’, such as comments between, or even in-between tokens. So better make sure to incorporate the input data properly into the SQL statement instead.